# i have a Soap error in SSL Symfony project

Tags: symfony, ssl, soap

in production, in https Symfony project !

i have this soapFault error in https :
**he work's in http**

```
SoapFault {#723 ▼
#message: "looks like we got no XML document"
#code: 0
#file: "/var/vhosts/admin-video/src/Controller/DefaultController.php"
#line: 141
+"faultstring": "looks like we got no XML document"
+"faultcode": "Client"
+"faultcodens": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
trace: {▼
/var/vhosts/admin-video/src/Controller/DefaultController.php:141 {▼
› );
line 141  › $result = $client->hello('toto');
› dump($result);
```

into a controller :

```
            $context = stream_context_create([
                'ssl' => [
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                ]
            ]);

            $client = new \SoapClient(
                "https://admin-******.im/recept?wsdl",
                array(

                    'trace' => 1,
                    'exceptions' => 0,
                    'location' => 'https://admin-******.im',
                    'uri' => 'https://admin-******.im/recept?wsdl',
                    'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
                    'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'stream_context' => $context
                )

            );
            $result = $client->__soapCall('hello', ['name' => 'toto']);
            dump($result);
```

help, please !
I looked on google but I can not find

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "he work's in http"? What do you have to change in your code to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried doing the request manually? What response do you get? The error message says "looks like we got no XML document" have you checked what you got back instead?

Answer (score 1):

in http, it's ok ! I get value

```
$client = new \SoapClient("http://admi*****i.im/recept?wsdl");
$result = $client->__soapCall('hello', ['name' => 'toto']);
dump($result);
```

in https :

```
...
$client = new \SoapClient("https://admi*****o.coi.im/recept?wsdl");
...
```

i have a SoapFault

- into a navigator : http://admi*****i.im/recept?wsdl
  xml is showing. it's ok

Answer (score 1):

I found, you had to write in full 'location' => 'uri…..?wsdl'